# Application becoming sluggish after generating rectangles

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am just playing around with arrays of rectangles in c# everything is working fine until I want to cycle between "layers" of rectangles, after cycling a few times to application (Silverlight) becomes very slow.

My code is as follows, would it be possible to offer any advice on what could be causing this degradation?

```
    private int worldHeight = 20;
    private int currentLayerNo = 0;
    private int keypressCounter = 0;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createGrid();
    }
    private void createGrid()
    {
        blockCanvas.Children.Clear();
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        Layer generateWorld = new Layer();
        generateWorld.z = worldHeight;
        generateWorld.x = 50;
        generateWorld.y = 50;
        generateWorld.Gen();
        Rectangle[,] currentLayer = generateWorld.createLayer(currentLayerNo);
        for (int a = 0; a < currentLayer.GetLength(0); a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < currentLayer.GetLength(1); b++)
            {
                Rectangle currentBlock = new Rectangle();
                currentBlock = currentLayer[a, b];
                blockCanvas.Children.Add(currentBlock);
                Canvas.SetTop(currentBlock, x);
                Canvas.SetLeft(currentBlock, y);
                y = y + 32;
            }
            x = x + 32;
            y = 0;
        }
        currentLayer = null;
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(onKeyDown);
    }
    private void onKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
               //Code here cycles between layers, each time calling the createGrid() method after altering currentLayerNo
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe drawing some circles from time to time, to make your app being motivated again? (Seriously: How about breaking down your really long source code to the actually interesting part?)

Comment: I've cut back on some of the code, Sorry about that - I guess it was a bit much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `createGrid()` you are also calling `this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(onKeyDown);` which adds a new event listener.

On the first call to `createGrid()` this means that on key down `createGrid()` will be called once, which will then register again for `KeyDown`, meaning will now be called twice.  On the next `KeyDown` event `createGrid()` is called twice and each time it adds itself to the `KeyDown` event.

Repeat until slow down.

You can put the registration in the MainPage constructor.

Comment: It seems so obvious now, Thanks Steve!

Answer (score 1):

Clearing and adding children on Canvas is performance intensive operation. If you want to improve performance, use caching. By this I mean instead of recreating all those rectangles, simply reuse them.

Reposition the ones you need, add extras if you need some or hide those that were created in the previous step, but will not be needed now.

Another reason for performance problem is that you have added the same event handler **over and over** again whenever you call creategrid. This means that when you press the key for the second time, you will call createGrid 2 times. On the each subsequent key press, you double the number of calls to createGrid.

Try to remove that line first and see if you need to use caching. I needed it in visually heavy WPF application and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I'll take a look into caching Toni, while moving the event handler out of the generate method fixed my performance issues for now, I feel that caching is worth looking into to get yet more speed from my application. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Like I've said, if you need to render many times per second, you must use caching since you need to avoid all the strain you can from measuring and drawing the layout.